# Basic cURL won't work

Tags: php, curl

I was trying to get hands on cURL and stuff like that, I just tried a simple and basic code, but it wont work for me.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/deathsquiid?api_key=apikeyhere');
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This won't get nothing back, cURL is enabled obviously..

Comment: What are the expected and actual results?

Comment: Have you tried changing the URL to something like google.com just to rule out any problems with the specific URL you are accessing?

Comment: I resolved just adding  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); since it was a https

Answer (score 0):

You should store the result of `curl_exec` on a variable like this:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/deathsquiid?   api_key=apikeyhere');
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
```

This is returning a JSON string with an access denied message, by the looks of the URL it seems that the API key is missing:`api_key=apikeyhere`